# Angular: FileReader - Store Files from Folder-Input in Array

Tags: angular, filereader

I have this input with which i Upload a Folder:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" id="file" (change)="readInput($event)" webkitdirectory directory multiple >
</div>
```

The Folder Contains a number of different csv files. 
For processing the input, I have this Filereader.

```
readInput(fileChangeEvent: Event) {
return new Observable<any>(obs => {
    const file = (fileChangeEvent.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
    if (file) {
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = e => {
        obs.next({
          result: fileReader.result
        });
      };
      fileReader.readAsText(file);
    }
  });
}
```

Now, the Observable of my Filereader seems to return the content of a random file from the folder. What i'd like to do would be to save the different Files-contents in an Array so that I could access them later in the code.

What I tried was adding the result to an array in the observable:

```
filearray = []

    readInput(fileChangeEvent: Event) {
    return new Observable<any>(obs => {
        const file = (fileChangeEvent.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
        if (file) {
          const fileReader = new FileReader();
          fileReader.onload = e => {
            obs.next({
                 this.filearray.push(result);
            });
          };
          fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        }
      });
    }
```

but this resulted in the array being empty.

How could I save the files in an array? Are there easier ways to handle a folder input than the FileReader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are uploading a folder and access only one file from the folder (`file[0]`).

If you need to read all the files, you can try something like this:

```
readInput(fileChangeEvent: Event) {
   this.readFile(0, files);
}

private readFile(index, files) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    if (index >= files.length ) {
      console.log(this.files);
      obs.next({result: this.files});
      return;
    }
    const file = files[index];
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      const bin = e.target.result;
      this.files.push(e.target.result);
      this.readFile(index + 1, files);
    };
      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  }
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/embed/angular-joe2p

Comment: This seems like a possible solution but i get two errors which i don't understand here. each time files is used : Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'. and at e.target.result:  Property 'result' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

Comment: I am still getting similar errors. Tried to reproduce it here https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-hksyx in the chart.component.ts

Comment: You forgot to declare some variables, It will work here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/angular-joe2p

Comment: Thank You! but what i am still confused about, does the readInput now return something? or else how could i subscribe to the data? when trying something like this.readInput(data).subscribe it won't work because "Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'"  https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-l8u16

Comment: I am trying to access the data after i've chosen the folder. Does it return the array or how can i use it?

Comment: If I try for example console.log(this.readInput(data)); it will show up as undefined

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a npm package like [angular-file-uploader](http://%20https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-uploader)

> Angular file uploader is an Angular 2/4/5/6 file uploader module with
>   Real-Time Progress Bar, Angular Universal Compatibility and multiple
>   themes which includes Drag and Drop and much more.

Demo: https://kzrfaisal.github.io/#/afu

---

Here is one example [How to handle folder uploads in Angular](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2018/01/03/folder-upload-in-an-angular-app/), if you want to implement your own solution.

---

One complete example [Creating a File Upload Component in Angular](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-file-upload-component-with-express/) with a complete [github repo](https://github.com/LukasMarx/angular-file-upload) to clone.